# Error in as.Date.default (df) do not know how to convert 'df[, 1]' to class “Date”

Tags: r

I have this dataset imported by read_excel

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  dates      local imported
  <date>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 2020-02-21   210        0
2 2020-02-22   250        0
3 2020-02-23   324        0
4 2020-02-24   406        0
5 2020-02-25   512        0
6 2020-02-26   450        0
```

I need to use this data with library(EpiEstim) that need data in this format:

`> df[,1] <- as.Date(df[,1])`

But, when I try

```
Error in as.Date.default(df[, 1]) : 
  do not know how to convert 'df[, 1]' to class “Date”
```

Do you know how can I solve it?
Ty!

Answer (score 2):

We need to extract the column with `$` as `as.Date` expects a `vector` as input

```
df$dates <- as.Date(df$dates)
```

Or use `[[`

```
 df[[1]] <- as.Date(df[[1]])
 df[['dates']] <- as.Date(df[['dates']])
```

---

The issue is that the `class` of the dataset is `tibble` and `tibble` doesn't coerce to `vector` when we use `[` as Extract i.e. it returns a single column `tibble`

```
str(as_tibble(mtcars)[,1])
#tibble [32 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#$ mpg: num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
```

and check with `[[` (returns a `vector`)

```
str(as_tibble(mtcars)[[1]])
#num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
```

Comment: I have already tried: with ```$``` it works without problems, but if I then try with ```[``` the result is the same

Comment: @FabioRiccardoColombo Please check my updated code

Comment: @FabioRiccardoColombo Also your `dates` are already `Date` class.  So, not sure why you need to again apply `as.Date`

Comment: I solved: I had loaded the data badly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

The error message is caused by some quirks of as.Date(). The workaround is to save the dataset as a csv file using write.csv() and then read in again as a csv using read.csv(). And then use as.Date(). This will eliminate the error message.

Another workaround is to use as.data.frame() first for your entire dataset before using as.Date().